# RenderScript V8 multiple dex files defined

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, renderscript

I'm trying to get this to work for some time now. 
I am using a module StackBlur https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur
This is how the Graddle file looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}

    task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
        destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
        baseName 'native-libs'
        extension 'jar'
        from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
        from fileTree(dir: 'renderscript', include: '**/*.so')
        into 'lib/'
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
    }
```

Everything from this library works perfectly. However, when I try to use RenderScript in my own project, with my own code. The troubles start. If I don't put RenderScript in my App graddle file I get the error:
`Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RSSupport from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[]: findLibrary returned null`
And when I put the renderscript values in my own Graddle file, there starts to be a dex file exception:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/Allocation$1;
```

The dexfile exception obviously happens because they both add the RenderScriptSupportEnabled true and RenderScriptTargetApi. But I do not know what I need to do to let them both work. Whenever I delete the renderscript in my own graddle, my project won't work, but when I delete it in the StackBlur module, that one will not work.
Any suggestions?
This is my graddle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package.name.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 19

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile project(':StackBlur')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after the 26th try I found out that these lines gave me the problems:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
   compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
}
```

I had to remove these, and clean the project.

Comment: Just cleaning the project solved the problem for me. Thanks for the suggestion